# Filtro de informacion con Openquery SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

actualmente tengo el siguiente script

```
DECLARE @TSQL VARCHAR(MAX) 
SELECT @TSQL = '

SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(RRPP,''

SELECT 

 d.Cuenta   AS "AccountNumber"
,D.Fecha AS "FechaPlanPago"
,d.Capital   AS "Capital"
,d.Interes   AS "Interes"

FROM PLANPAGO D

WHERE D.Fecha BETWEEN '' and ''
'')
'

EXECUTE(@TSQL)
```

el cual realiza un Openquery a otra base de datos, el siguiente me trae la siguiente informacion

```
AccountNumber   FechaPlanPago   Capital   Interes
100122              21/12/2007  977.85    133.34
100122              21/1/2008   1008.87   151.94
100122              8/2/2008    0         71.57
100122              21/2/2008   1037.54   51.7
100122              21/3/2008   1073.08   87.73
100122              21/4/2008   1097.52   63.29
100122              21/5/2008   1129.72   8675.01
100481              27/7/2007   0         0
100481              1/9/2007    604.94    132
100481              13/9/2007   0.01      37.35
100481              1/10/2007   643.57    56.02
100481              4/10/2007   26.47     7.57
100481              1/11/2007   632.28    69.94
100481              1/12/2007   679.39    57.55
100481              14/12/2007  0.04      16.84
100481              1/1/2008    696.74    23.32
100481              1/2/2008    716.56    20.36
101272              14/8/2007   0         0
101272              14/9/2007   1752.68   568.33
101272              15/10/2007  1802.48   518.53
101272              14/11/2007  1868.78   452.23
101272              14/12/2007  1920.17   400.84
101272              14/1/2008   1961.37   359.64
```

lo que quiero es una forma para que solo me traiga una sola linea por AccountNumber, con la fecha mas reciente, por ejemplo:

para el AccountNumber 100122 el resultado que espero es este

```
100122              21/5/2008   1129.72   8675.01
```

Para el 100481

```
100481              14/12/2007  0.04      16.84
```

Entonces el resultado final que espero es el siguiente:

```
AccountNumber   FechaPlanPago   Capital   Interes
100122              21/5/2008   1129.72   8675.01
100481              14/12/2007  0.04      16.84
101272              14/1/2008   1961.37   359.64
```

Como puedo realizar lo que requiero, con el script de arriba

Comment: ¿La otra base de datos es SQL Server? ¿qué versión? ¿qué tipo de dato es la columna fecha?

Comment: es AS400, y es tipo DATE la Fecha

Comment: ¿Qué versión de DB2?

Comment: esa info si la desconozco de momento

Comment: Hola Beterson podrías decir si las respuestas dadas te resultaron útiles, y marcar como aceptada la que consideres que más te haya ayudado, gracias

Answer (score 3):

Las versiones modernas de DB2 soportan [CTE's](https://www.db2tutorial.com/db2-basics/db2-cte/) y [funciones de ventana](https://www.db2tutorial.com/db2-window-functions/), como [row_number()](https://www.db2tutorial.com/db2-window-functions/db2-row_number/), de tal manera que podrías re-escribir tu consulta para que, desde la base de datos de origen, vengan solamente los datos que te interesan.

Para no hacer la respuesta más complicada de lo que debe ser, me concentraré primero en la consulta que se lanza contra DB2, que podría quedar como esta:

```
with
PlanPagoOrdenado as (
SELECT   d.Cuenta   AS "AccountNumber"
       , d.Fecha    AS "FechaPlanPago"
       , d.Capital  AS "Capital"
       , d.Interes  AS "Interes"
       , row_number() over (partition by d.Cuenta order by d.Fecha desc) as NumeroFila
  FROM PLANPAGO D
)
select AccountNumber, FechaPlanPago, Capital, Interes
  from PlanPagoOrdenado
 where NumeroFila = 1
```

Acá, dentro del CTE `PlanPagoOrdenado` estoy valiéndome de la función row_number() para *numerar* las filas de cada cuenta, en orden cronológico inverso y en el select final me aseguro de quedarme solamente con la fila que tiene el número 1, que es la de la fecha más reciente para cada cuenta.

Sugiero que la consulta aislada sea probada directamente en un cliente de DB2 primero. Una vez esté funcionando, la trasladas tal cual a tu consulta dentro de la sentencia OpenQuery del SQL Server. Si no tuviera modificaciones, quedaría, por ejemplo:

```
ECLARE @TSQL VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @TSQL = '
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(RRPP,''
with
PlanPagoOrdenado as (
SELECT   d.Cuenta   AS "AccountNumber"
       , d.Fecha    AS "FechaPlanPago"
       , d.Capital  AS "Capital"
       , d.Interes  AS "Interes"
       , row_number() over (partition by d.Cuenta order by d.Fecha desc) as NumeroFila
  FROM PLANPAGO D
)
select AccountNumber, FechaPlanPago, Capital, Interes
  from PlanPagoOrdenado
 where NumeroFila = 1
'')
';

EXECUTE(@TSQL);
```

**OJO:** he omitido intencionalmente el filtro de fechas (between), pues le faltan datos y le faltan comillas, que probablemente has omitido o cambiado al publicar la pregunta. Si lo necesitas, colócalo de la manera correcta en la consulta que está *dentro* del CTE.

Answer (score 2):

Si tu otra base de datos fuera **SQL Server** prueba esta consulta:

```
select T.AccountNumber, T.FechaPlanPago, T.Capital, T.Interes
from
(
 select 
  AccountNumber, 
  FechaPlanPago, 
  Capital, 
  Interes,
  Row_Number() Over(Partition by AccountNumber order by FechaPlanPago desc) fila
 from PlanPago
) T
Where T.fila = 1
```

Lo que se hace aquí es una subconsulta, la cual hace uso de la **función Row_Number** para proyectar una nueva columna la cual va a tener como valores una secuencia de números consecutivos, esta secuencia se incrementará mientras los valores de la **columna AccountNumber** sean iguales, cuando encuentre un valor diferente se reiniciará la secuencia y volverá a incrementarse hasta que se encuentre un nuevo valor, en la **función Row_Number** se hace uso de la **cláusula order by** para ordenar por el campo o campos deseados, en nuestro caso ordenamos descendentemente por el **campo FechaPlanPago**, de esta forma tenemos todos nuestros grupos de **AccountNumber** numerados y ordenados descendentemente quedando siempre la fecha más reciente como la primera por cada grupo, a esta columna se le da como alias el nombre **fila**. Sobre esta subconsulta se hace entonces una consulta más general la cual va a filtrar todos los registros cuyo **campo fila** sea igual a **1**, de esta forma seleccionamos la fecha más reciente por cada **AccountNumber**.